# Connection to Oracle works through a console application and doesn't work through a web service

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, connection, oracleclient

I can't connect to an Oracle schema through a asmx web service instead of I can through a console application [x86].

The code:

```
var conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=xe;User ID=mySchema;Password=myPass");
```

The exception:

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

The environment: Windows 7 x64 - VS 2008.

Any idea?

kindly ask me for any extra information

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the console application and web service running from the same host?  Are your sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora files setup correctly to allow you names resolution for the DB specified?  Have you tried to TNSPing the host that you are attempting to connect to?  Does it resolve?

Comment: @DarkBobG: Yes, they're from the same host. and I tried TNSPing, it resolved the alias. it's OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OCI, the Oracle client layer on which ODP (or the native Oracle client layer) is based has a bug that prevents any application located in a folder containing parentheses () from running properly

This bug is very visible since the apparition of the Program Files (x86) folder...

The host running your application (typically IIS) is probably located in the x86 folder, hence the issue. Your console app works fine because it's probably located in a folder that does not have the issue.

More info and a few solutions [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2010/01/26/connectivity-issue-with-oracle-in-x64-environment-ora-12154-tns-could-not-resolve-the-connect-identifier-specified.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Oracle guy in any way but I've run into similar situations in other databases. The problem we had was that the DSN was created as a User DSN and not a System DSN. I don't know how Oracle data sources are created but I would check this out.

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same issue. I resolved by referencing `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` instead of `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`.