# Connection to Oracle works through a console application and doesn't work through a web application - ORA-12154

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, connection, oracleclient

My question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681532/connection-to-oracle-works-through-a-console-application-and-doesnt-work-throug). But I'm pretty sure that there is no parentheses in web-application directory because it looks like "D:\Work\MyProject\portal\Web"

In my ISession object getting error in Connection property saying:

```
*ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified*
```

It is happening when debugging web-application from localhost in Visual Studio 2010.

But when executing the same code in console application it works perfectly. 
Connection string is in form of "Data Source=SERVER/oracle;User Id=USER;Password=PASS;"

My development environment summary:

win7 x64 sp1, 
oracle.dataaccess.dll version 10.2.0.100, 
ms visual studio 2010

**UPDATED**

I have changeddeal with Connection property in web application and can in console... But now I have another error:

```
Unable to load DLL 'OraOps10.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

I have completely reinstalled oracle client 10g. I even tried to set all of my projects to x86 (earlier were Any CPU). I have checked .Net Framework version and it is 3.5

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your ORACLE_HOME (path)
2. Check privilegies on the oracle home directory.
3. Check your references in your web app(should be to Oracle.DataAccess and also System.Data).

Comment: My ORACLE_HOME is empty. I have tried to set ORACLE_HOME to my install directory C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_2\BIN but with no effect. And, of course, I have reference to Oracle.DataAccess set to copy local